# Why can't I include user defined settings as variables in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings

I'm trying to do something really silly: show some settings variables in a Django template (using Django 1.5). So, if I try this:

```
<p>Timezone: {{ TIME_ZONE }}</p>
```

I get the timezone defined in my settings file. So far, so good.

But now, let say I define this new setting:

```
FOO = 'bar'
```

And try:

```
<p>Foo: {{ FOO }}</p>
```

I can't see the variable's value. Why?

I know I can pass variables to templates from views, but what if I want to define a name and description for my project in just one place and show them in any template? This is one of the simple tasks I want to do.

This kind of problem suggests me I'm not doing things properly (meaning properly "how Django thinks that should be done"), but I don't know why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a TIME_ZONE variable available in your templates because you have `django.core.context_processors.tz` context processor enabled in your settings. 
Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#get-current-timezone.

For other settings you'd need to write your own context processor or send your settings values from the view. 
You can import your project's settings like that: `from django.conf import settings`. 
Docs advise to use it instead of your local settings file.

You can find details here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-in-python-code

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That solves the problem. But then I have a doubt: writing a context processor is the simplest way to provide a user defined global variable to be shown in any template? Apart from passing that variable to the template every time I want to show it (that doesn't sound 'elegant')

Comment: Well, it can't be simplier than that.If you haven't yet, cast a look here - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors